# If two Gaussian random variables are uncorrelated, they are statistically independent

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, correlation

I read in a textbook that when two gaussian variables are uncorrelated, then they are statistically independent? How can I prove that?

Comment: You can't prove that because it is not true in general.  Uncorrelated _jointly Gaussian_ random variables are independent.  If the random variables are Gaussian but not jointly Gaussian, then they could be uncorrelated and yet be dependent.  There are standard examples.  Search this web site for other answers to this problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/609732/321264

Comment: @DilipSarwate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

Comment: @DilipSarwate  I was pointing out to a full proof/example about what you mentioned. I believe links belong to the comment section and not to full answers :)

Comment: @MarineGalantin.Oh, OK. I didn't check the link and thought you were pointing out that Wikipedia was _contradictng_ what I wrote. May I suggest that we delete this entire conversation (including your pointing out Wikipedia) and you write a slightly different comment like "An example of what Dilip Sarwate is pointing out can be found in Wikipedia here......" ?  I will delete my query (previous comment) and this comment in a day or two.  Note tha Michael Hardy's answer already includes a link to the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent) is a counterexample.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) is the definition of "'jointly' normally distributed".  This article states, but I'm not sure it proves, that *jointly* normally distributed random variables are independent if they are uncorrelated.

Answer (score 2):

If $X$ and $Y$ are jointly gaussian, and uncorrelated, you can show that
$$f_{XY}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y);$$
this assures independence.

Comment: But be sure to check out [this recent question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21429/6633) on stats.SE where a related issue regarding independence is being discussed.

Answer (score 2):

The covariance matrix of uncorrelated random variables $X$ and $Y$ is a diagonal matrix. If the two random variables are jointly Gaussian, we can write the joint PDF as

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^2\cdot|K|}}\cdot e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^TK^{-1}(x-\mu)}{2}}$$
where K is the covariance matrix of X and Y,
$$K = \begin{bmatrix}
 \sigma_x^2 & 0 \\ 
 0 & \sigma_y^2 
\end{bmatrix}.$$
If we use this $K$ in above equation, we can split the joint pdf into marginal pdf of $X$ and $Y$, hence independence is proved.

Answer (score -6):

Two random variables, X,Y, are said to be uncorrelated if their co-variance, E(XY) − E(X)E(Y), is zero.

This mean :
E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)

then , they are statistically independent