# Normally distributed and uncorrelated and dependent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I read that :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent

And I can't understand how this is not in contradiction with that :

[Jointly Gaussian uncorrelated random variables are independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/609732/jointly-gaussian-uncorrelated-random-variables-are-independent)

can anyone explain me why those are not contradictory ? What assumptions in the theorem are not respected in the examples of the first link?

---

For me, if one look at the joint distribution, it is normal and it can be splited into two normals. Why isn't it the case in the example given on wikipedia ?

> The question has been asked plenty of times on mathstack. I am not
>   searching for a counter example, neither for the proof. I am searching
>   for the understanding between the two theorems.

Comment: At the first link the joint distribution is the product of two different distributions, where one is **not normally** distributed. There is no direct link to the joint distribution of two normal distributed random variables.

Answer (score 1):

The first link concerns arbitrary joint distributions for which each variable's marginal distribution is univariate Gaussian. The second link concerns one such joint distribution, a multivariate generalization of the univariate case.

Comment: can you be more explicite please ? I still don't get it...

Comment: @MarineGalantin To take the first link's first example, $X,\,Y$ have joint probability density $\frac{1}{\sqrt{8\pi}}\exp-\frac{x^2}{2}[\delta(x-y)+\delta(x+y)]$, [which is clearly not multivariate Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function). (Before you ask, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) is what $\delta$ is.)

Comment: Also, what is the difference between multivariate gaussian and joint gaussian ?

Comment: @MarineGalantin I never used the phrase "joint Gaussian". Whatever $X,\,Y$ are, they have *a joint distribution*. Given that joint distribution, you can obtain the respective *marginal distributions* of each variable. The first link is about what happens when, even though the same marginals are obtained as in the special case where the joint distribution is a mutlivariate Gaussian, *the joint distribution is not in fact a mutlivariate Gaussian*.

Comment: I still don't get it, the $X$ and $Y$ you mentionned comment nr $2$ are normal, uncorrelated, but dependant ? And that's not in contradiction with link nr $2$? sorry I can't understand it yet.

Comment: @MarineGalantin Link 2's "terms and conditions" include one condition the example in the first link violates, that the *joint distribution* takes a very specific form.

Comment: where? I don't see any "terms and conditions"

Comment: @MarineGalantin Note the second link's top answer unpacks the term "joint normally distributed" for two variables as meaning they have a *bivariate* (and hence multivariate) Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 0):

There's no contradiction because the random variables $X, Y$ in the first wikipedia link are not jointly normally distributed since $P(X+Y=0)=1/2$.

Comment: I don't get it. What s different from having two random normal variable, and them beeing jointly normal?